# Tabs em css - quebra de linha quando estoura o limite da pagina

Tags: css

Estou fazendo Abas em css. porém, quando chega a um determinado numero, ela quebra pra linha de baixo. Eu queria que ficasse sempre, em linha, mesmo que não apareça na pagina.

```css
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, .2);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .tabs::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .3);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .tabs::before {
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #ECECEC;
    cursor: pointer;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  
  .tabs li::before,
  .tabs li::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    content: " ";

    border: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .3);
  }

  .tabs li::before {
    left: -6px;
  }

  .tabs li::after {
    right: -6px;
  }

  .tabs li.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);

    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .tabs li {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  }

  .tabs li:before {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  }

  .tabs li:after {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  }

  .tabs li::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7pt;
    position: absolute;
    content: "\f410";
    top: -1px;
    right: 2px;
    color: red;
  }
  .tabs li {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
</ul>

<section data-role="tabs-contents">
  <article data-mni="mniLotes">Conteudo do Lote</article>
  <article data-mni="mniLancamentos">Conteudo do Lançamento</article>
  <article data-mni="mniDash">Conteudo do Dashboard</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o seu problema, através desta resposta da comunidade em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679804/prevent-wrapping-of-containers-span-or-div

Nesse sentido, já que a resposta deles é em inglês, resolvi responder invés de sinalizar duplicata.

```css
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, .2);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll; /* Acrescentei */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Acrescentei */
  }

  .tabs::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .3);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .tabs::before {
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #ECECEC;
    cursor: pointer;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  
  .tabs li::before,
  .tabs li::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    content: " ";

    border: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .3);
  }

  .tabs li::before {
    left: -6px;
  }

  .tabs li::after {
    right: -6px;
  }

  .tabs li.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);

    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .tabs li {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  }

  .tabs li:before {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  }

  .tabs li:after {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  }

  .tabs li::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7pt;
    position: absolute;
    content: "\f410";
    top: -1px;
    right: 2px;
    color: red;
  }
  .tabs li {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
  <li class="tabs-item active">Geral</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Documentos</li>
  <li class="tabs-item">Tarefas</li>
</ul>

<section data-role="tabs-contents">
  <article data-mni="mniLotes">Conteudo do Lote</article>
  <article data-mni="mniLancamentos">Conteudo do Lançamento</article>
  <article data-mni="mniDash">Conteudo do Dashboard</article>
</section>
```